# using service filter events with RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am concluding that I dont use RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync in the intended way as it dont work for me :)

I have a statefull service running with the following exposed method for remoting

```
    public async Task RegisterServiceNotification(string serviceNameUri)
    {

            var notifications = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, long>>("ServiceNotifications");
            using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
            {
                await notifications.GetOrAddAsync(tx, serviceNameUri, (serviceName) =>
                {

                    logger.LogInformation("Registering notification filter for {serviceName}", serviceName);
                    var filterDescription = new ServiceNotificationFilterDescription
                    {
                        Name = new Uri(serviceName)
                    };


                    return fabricClient.ServiceManager.RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync(filterDescription).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                });

                await tx.CommitAsync();
            }

    }
```

From the same stateless service I am calling it using remoting to reroute based on a partition hashing

```
 public async Task RegisterGatewayServiceAsync(GatewayServiceRegistrationData data)
 {
 ....
     await GatewayManagementServiceClient.GetProxy<IServiceNotificationService>(this.Context.ServiceName.AbsoluteUri, data.ServiceName.AbsoluteUri)
                    .RegisterServiceNotification(data.ServiceName.AbsoluteUri);
 ....
 }
```

and my GetProxy looks like the following:

```
public static T GetProxy<T>(string service,string partition) where T : IService => CreateProxyFactoryFabricTransport().CreateServiceProxy<T>(new Uri(service), partition.ToPartitionHashFunction());
```

I do this as I assume I should only call `RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync` once per service i want notifications for. Wrong/Correct?

Then since i want each partition in the statefull service to listen to these events i will call OnNotification once per statefullservice

```
  public sealed class GatewayManagementService : StatefulService
  {
       private bool notificationRegistered = false;

        public async Task RegisterGatewayServiceAsync(GatewayServiceRegistrationData data)
        {
        ...
            if(!notificationRegistered)
            {
                fabricClient.ServiceManager.ServiceNotificationFilterMatched += OnNotification;
                notificationRegistered = true;
                logger.LogInformation("ServiceNotificationEvent registered for on {node}",Context.NodeContext.NodeName);


            }
       ....
       }
  }
```

But now a few weeks later I dont see any log outputs from the `OnNotification` event for when service changes.
Should i be calling RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync more often ? Am I wrong with my assumptions above, what can i do differently? I havent been able to find docs helping me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync is associated with a fabric client. All notifications are raised in that fabric client. If you need notifications to come to multiple fabric clients, each of those need to register.
Is that respected in your code?

Comment: Thank you, no thats not how i designed my application. I will rethink my application.

Comment: So if two fabric clients call RegisterServiceNotificationFilterAsync - and both add event listeners - fabricClient.ServiceManager.ServiceNotificationFilterMatched += OnNotification;  You are saying each client will only get notified once?

Comment: I think one of my issues in the beginning was that I was seeing multiple event raised at ServiceNotificationFilterMatched and therefor assumed it registered the filters globally.

Comment: will test it again and get back with my findings.

Comment: The information about registered filters is kept per client. So each client that registers gets notifications for the matched filter. Each will get notification for one event once.